# Return ID in ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a ajax function that returns a smaller distance calculation done in php I need it to return the userid but it only returns -Infinity me on my browser log where I am going wrong can help me

my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data : formula,
    url : 'http://10.0.0.119/melleve/statusorig2.php',
    success : function(data){
        var retorno = JSON.parse(data);
        var mapdistance = $.map(retorno, function(index, value) {
            return index + value;
        });
        var ok = Math.max.apply(Math, mapdistance);
        alert(ok);
```

My php

```
$latuser = '-22.8650697';
$longuser = '-43.287510499999996';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cadast_moto WHERE carmodel = '2'"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$encode = array();

while ($res = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $arr = array('idmoto' => $res['idmoto'], 'nomemoto' => $res['nomemoto'], 'latitude' => $res['latitude'], 'longitude' => $res['longitude']);
    //$encode[] = $arr;
    //echo (json_encode($arr));
    $theta = $longuser - $res['longitude'];
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($latuser)) * sin(deg2rad($res['latitude'])) +  cos(deg2rad($latuser)) * cos(deg2rad($res['latitude'])) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $finaldist = $miles * 1.609344;
    $encode[$res['idmoto']] = $finaldist;
}
//echo $finaldist;
//echo (json_encode($finaldist));
echo (json_encode($encode));
```

Comment: give us some example parameters instead of the database stuff and please remove the javaScript code from this question... looks too ugly. it could be, that you will not need an answer for the php part anymore...

Comment: Why are you returning `index + value` in the `$.map` loop? That will result in a string, not a number, so then you're trying to use `Math.max` on an array of strings.

Comment: Hello I am returning index + value because so and the ID appears at the end of the calculation of the numbers, it was only for a test and ended up sending along with the question I ask forgiveness, the loop function and Math work very well Max is me informing the greatest value and min informing me the least value is everything working as it should but what I want is that instead he return the higher / lower value me return the ID which belong the higher / lower value.